# Using extension methods in scripting APIs in Roslyn throws an exception

Tags: c#, dynamic, roslyn

I'm trying to do the following:

```
ScriptOptions optins = ScriptOptions.Default
     .AddReferences(typeof(HelperExtensionMethods).Assembly,...);

var globals = new ParamsVM { X = var1, Y = var2 };

var task = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(
    "X.MyExtensionMethod() == Y.AnotherExtensionMethod()",
    optins,
    globals
    );

task.Wait();
var res = task.Result;
```

Let's consider `X` and `Y` are of type `T1` ...
Where `HelperExtensionMethods` defined like this:

```
public static class HelperExtensionMethods
{
   public static string MyExtensionMethod(this T1 src) { ... }
   public static string AnotherExtensionMethod(this object src) { ... }
}
```

`EvaluateAsync` throws an exception says:

> error CS1061: 'T1' does not contain a definition for 'MyExtensionMethod' and no extension method 'MyExtensionMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'T1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

What is the correct way to add class `HelperExtensionMethods` to the `optins` I tried `WithImports` and `AddImports` with no luck.

I also moved to `Roslyn` from `DynamicExpresso` library because of some limitations there.